# I wanna make a simple code from this

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

So, I have for JTextfields in my program, but if I check it whether empty or not, it will make my code longer and not effective. Is there any code that simpler than this?

```
if (t_ipA.getText() == null || t_ipA.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                 // your code here
            }
```

Note : I have : t_ipA .. t_ipD, t_maskA .. t_maskD
There is eight JTextfields.

-------edit---------
Okay, now I have resolved my own question.

this is the code, I've been using :
This is the method :

```
    private boolean isEmpty(JTextField f) {
    if (f==null || f.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        f.setText("0");
    }
    return f.getText().trim().isEmpty();

}
```

and this is in actionlistener :

```
isEmpty(t_ipA);
isEmpty(t_ipB);
isEmpty(t_ipC);
isEmpty(t_ipD);

isEmpty(t_maskA);
isEmpty(t_maskB);
isEmpty(t_maskC);
isEmpty(t_maskD);
```

But then, I still searching for using array list for make this code simpler.

Thanks to QBrute, JBNizet, and Mureinik

Comment: Write a method that does the check and call this method with each of the text fields.

Comment: getText() will never return null.

Comment: Ummm can you show me the example? I am new to programming. thanks

Comment: `boolean isBlank(JTextField t) { return t.getText().trim().isEmpty(); }`. You should be able to create methods if you want to use Swing. That's basic stuff that needs to be mastered before using a complex API like Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can define a method to encapsulate the check:

```
private boolean isEmpty(JTextField f) {
    return f.getText() == null || f.getText().trim().isEmpty();
}
```

Then, you could place all your fields in a list or array, and use Java 8's streaming API to apply the condition to all of them. E.g.:

```
List<JTextFeild> fields = Arrays.asList(t_ipA, t_ipB /* etc... */);
if (fields.stream().allMatch(this::isEmpty)) {
    // your code here...
}
```

Comment: the second code give me error : "the type list is not generic it cannot be parameterized with arguments". I have added java.awt.List; java.util.arrays

Comment: The right List class is in java.util. Not in java.awt.

Comment: ok JB Nizet, but now the method allMatch....is not aplicable for (this::isEmpty), and the new action Listener is doesnt define (JTextfield) that is applicable here